# Visual Studio 2008 Build Dependency Chain

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am having an issue with Visual Studio 2008 SP1. Basically, I have a .NET 3.5 solution with a client, shared and server component. While coding, all components run on the same box, but in production the server component is a standalone (remoting) service running on a separate server.

I would expect that a change to the client component would require only a rebuild of that component as there is no client/server dependency. This is in fact how it works on my work PC. However, on my personal PC and another co-worker's PC, any modification - even a simple label change on the client, requires the server component service to be stopped so that the solution can be rebuilt in its entirety. Does anyone know if there is a particular setting that controls this??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK folks. The problem was more simple than I at first thought. On the PCs that this did not work as desired I had to turn on the Visual Studio setting (Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run) named "Only build startup projects and dependencies on run". This appears to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check Assembly Version.
Your problem sounds like you have automatic Assembly Version change each build, and because of this the compatibility broken.