# How to prevent Visual Studio from starting up a Windows/Console Application when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows

I've a solution with two projects on VS2008: an ASP.NET Web App and a Windows App. They don't depend on eachother.

Is it possible to prevent Visual Studio from doing a "Start project" for the Windows App when I'm Debugging?

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734573/preventing-visual-studio-from-building-all-projects-when-debugging-one) question are solving a similar issue with WCF Apps but not with Windows Apps.

Thank you in advance.

Juan Hoyos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To set the solution startup project:**

1. *Right-Click* on the Solution
2. *Select* Single Startup Project
3. *Select* Your Web Application
4. *Click* OK

**To set the web application as the startup project:**

1. *Right-Click* on the Web Application Project
2. *Click* Set as StartUp Project

**To manually run the web application:**

1. *Right-Click* on the Web Application Project
2. *Select* Debug
3. *Select* Start New Instance

Comment: That was it!
Although hunter and madmik3 pointed a solution, hunter explained it more deeply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to set the startup on any project by right clicking and selecting "start as startup".  You can also set a start page for an ASP.NET App by clicking that page and saying "set as start page"