# Migrating a build to VSTS - get warning messages and no artifacts in the drop folder

Tags: azure-devops

I have a legacy application where I want to migrate the build to VSTS.
In the application is a web project and a WCF API that I want to include in the build, and a WIN RT client project that should not be included.
So I instead of having a single Visual Studio task to build the sln file, I have 2 which build the web and WCF projects individually one after the other.
See
[image]

Although the build is successful, I get these warnings and I would like to know how to fix them;
[image]

The log files can be found here; https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArKf9AZKW_zWgRapkZ_IUT-DrhY0

The property groups in my csproj file are;

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If I replace the build for 2 project csproj files with one with the overall sln file, I get these error messages;

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2049):C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2049,5):
>   Error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built
>   "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Bing.Maps.Xaml,
>   Version=1.313.0825.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
>   through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
>   supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2049):C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2049,5):
>   Error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built
>   "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs,
>   Version=12.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
>   through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
>   supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2606):C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2606,5):
>   Error : Copying file Service
>   References\SurveyServiceReference\M.Survey.SurveyAdminApp.SurveyServiceReference.AssignedJobs.datasource
>   to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Service
>   References\SurveyServiceReference\M.Survey.SurveyAdminApp.SurveyServiceReference.AssignedJobs.datasource
>   failed. Could not find file 'Service
>   References\SurveyServiceReference\M.Survey.SurveyAdminApp.SurveyServiceReference.AssignedJobs.datasource'.
>   Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the parameters to the MsBuild Arguments and that these are a valid combination for your project, e.g.:

```
/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU
```

Or edit the project file and make sure the default Configuration and Platform are specified in the first PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion and I got the same result. I looked at the second, but I found my propertyGroups were already set like that anyway.

Comment: Do you have a property group that has the condition for the specified configuration and platform?

Comment: I have now put the property group details in the question

Answer (score 0):

It turned out **it caused by the variable `BuildPlatform` = `any cpu` in your build definition**.

You should change the variable `BuildPlatform` with the value **`anycpu`** (no blank space) to align with the value in PropertyGroups of your .csproj.

[image]

Comment: Ok. I tried that originally but I had problems because in the sln file there is a WinRT project that I do not want included in the build. It looks like this caused the build to fail. How do I specify not to include that project in the build?

Comment: Also I want to get the web project and the wcf api to be deployed in 2 seperate locations, not sure how I do that. I think I need the build to locate the artifacts in 2 seperate drop folders

Comment: I updated the question to let you see the error messages I get when I try to build the solution.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can change the variable `BuildPlatform` with the value `anucpu`, then it should build correctly and copy the packages to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

Comment: I now get this message "d:\a\1\s\M.Survey.sln.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "release|anycpu" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration."

Comment: What's the result if you leave it blank?

Comment: Still get d:\a\1\s\M.Survey.sln.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "release|AnyCPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

Comment: Can you share an example code in one drive which can reproduce the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160183/discussion-between-arame3333-and-marina-liu-msft).

Answer (score 0):

The Visual studio build task does have this weird behavior. When building a solution or `.sln` file, you have to provide the build platform in the following manner: **With a space in between**

[image]

However, when you are building a project or a `.csproj` file, you have to provide the build platform in the following manner: **Without any space in between**

[image]

If building the project individually doesn't work for you, and you need to build the solution, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734573/preventing-visual-studio-from-building-all-projects-when-debugging-one) SO post will help you make solution level changes in Visual Studio so when you build in VSTS, the task will only build the desired projects. Hope this helps.